# How do I get the file system id for aws-cdk EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-efs

```
const fileSystem = new efs.CfnFileSystem(this, 'EFS', {}); //This creates the file system
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'FileSystemID', { value: fileSystem.???? });
```

I need the filesystemid to pass as an environment variable to other resources

Answer (score 2):

```
const fileSystem = new efs.CfnFileSystem(this, 'EFS', {

    });


    const mount = new efs.CfnMountTarget(this, 'MountTarget', {

      fileSystemId: fileSystem.ref,
      securityGroups: [vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup],
      subnetId: vpc.publicSubnets[0].subnetId,

    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'FileSystemId', { value: mount.fileSystemId });
```